# math.net matrix juxtaposition

Tags: matrix, f#, math.net

What is the math.net equivalent of this type of MATLAB operations on matrices for matrix juxtaposition?

```
A = [2 2; 3 3]
B = [4 4; 5 5]
C = [A B]
D = [A; B]
```

Is there a cheat sheet that compares MATLAB/NUMPY to Math.net? That may help me in the future.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a relatively eye-pleasing solution:

```
let C = A.append(B)
let D = B.stack(D)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs here: http://nmath.sourceforge.net/doc/numerics/

I think the best solution would be something like:

```
let retmatrix = Matrix(A.RowCount + B.RowCount, A.ColumnCount)
retmatrix.SetMatrix(0,A.RowCount,0,A.ColumnCount,A)
retmatrix.SetMatrix(A.RowCount,A.RowCount+B.RowCount,0,B.RowCount,B)
```